# c program to print min number of days required to spread rumour in matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

c program to print minimum number of days required to spread rumour in matrix to all houses located like a matrix of m*n. It takes exactly one day to travel rumour from 1 house to other rumour travels only horizontally or vertically
Here is code i have written but it is not getting accepted might be wrong at higher inputs.1<=m<=100000 and 1<=n<=100000.

here is my code

```
  #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  long m,n,days;
  scanf("%ld",&m);
        scanf("%ld",&n);
  if(m<1||m>1000000||n<1||n>1000000)
    return 0;
  if(m==2&&n==2)
    printf("3");
  else 
        if((m+n)%2==0)
        days=(m+n)/2;
        else
        days=(m+n)/2+1;
        printf("%ld",days);
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: `if(m<1||m>1000000||n<1||n>1000000)` is it _all_ you want?

Comment: yes they have mentioned that range input should be in that.

Comment: hmm, but why `long` for a max value of `100000`?

Comment: it is out of range of int thats why i thought it would be better to take wider range data type..

Comment: if you have any alternative logic then tell me.

Comment: wait, out of range? for what? an `int`? AFAIK,with `gcc` and any 32 bit system, `int` spreads 32 bits, which should be more than enough. Makes sense?

Comment: Can you please clarify on "but it is not getting accepted"?

Comment: @AndrewCorsini maybe some online coding sites..... :-)

Comment: What do you mean? I just want him to expand on what the actual problem is

Comment: @AndrewCorsini I'm not _questioning_ your question, just guessing... :-)

Comment: I see that you read the `n x m`, the matrix size, but where do you start the gossip? Does the first "rumour transfer" count? Other than that, this is a simple "flooding" algorithm. The time of the spread is the fill time of the farthest corner. So, please link or edit into the question the problem statement.

Comment: @saurav its not issue whether it is int or long ..for all possible inputs i tried im getting correct answer. if u have any alternative logic or any logical mistake in code then tell me

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, the rumour starts in a corner. From any corner, the farthest corner is `n+m-1` steps away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way that the rumour will travel is when the roumor starts in the middle of the matrix.

Since it travels only horizontally or vertically, if it starts from the middle then it will take `m/2 + n/2` days to reach a corner in the worst case.

Just try this `printf("%d\n",m/2+n/2);` it should work.

NOTE: Add 1 if you have to include a day for the starting house.

Comment: thank u...by your logic i got correct answer

Comment: @amit ghadage you can thank me by accepting my answer :)